# SQL Query with parameters from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

Column A in Excel Sheet 1 contains e.g. 10 values (A1,A2...A10).

These should be used as parameters in a query like the below. Note that the number of parameters is not static.

```
SELECT Name FROM Person WHERE SSN in (A1,A2..A10)
```

The Name of the people should be returned in Sheet 2.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? And how?

Comment: Did you try using JOINS?

Comment: Do the value sin A1 - A10 always correspond to the SSN?  Is the query going to always be against the Person table? Does it matter how the names are placed onto Sheet 2?  What have you tried so far?